# How to install SQL Server ODBC driver on OSX?

Tags: macos, drivers, sql-server, odbc, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench on a Macbook to migrate a SQL Server database to MySQL. When I try to connect to SQL Server I get the error:

> The ODBC driver that was selected for the source connection was not found by the ODBC manager.
>   Ensure that you have the proper ODBC driver installed and retry.
>
> Error Text: Error("('00000', '[00000] [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen({FreeTDS}, 6): image not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.connect

But I don't know what I need to do to "install" a driver. I tried installing FreeTDS via homebrew, but nothing has changed. I've tried installing [ODBC Manager](http://www.odbcmanager.net/) but that doesn't seem to actually do anything, I still need to add a driver from somewhere (I don't see any relevant files in the homebrew folder to add).

Can someone explain in simple steps what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Easiest is a commercial solution, such as [that available from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver/). Homebrew and related solutions usually require a good deal of under-the-covers tinkering, as these don't usually conform to Apple guidelines, so things you'd expect to succeed, fail, and things you'd expect to fail, succeed...